# SQL Query using the parameter and like word

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a requirement, I have to pass the parameter @ClientName to query and I have to use @ClientName to use in the like filter.

Please see below.

```
DECLARE @ClientName VARCHAR(20) = 'abc'
SELECT ID,ClientName
FROM    ClientTable
WHERE   ClientName LIKE '%@ClientNAme%'
```

Please let me know, if there any another alternate to acheive this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use plain concatenation inline:

```
WHERE ClientName LIKE '%' + @ClientName + '%'
```

Or you can control this behavior more directly by allowing the wildcards to be optional. If your query is this:

```
WHERE ClientName LIKE @ClientName
```

Then you can force different behavior (starts with, contains, or ends with) using one of the following:

```
SET @ClientName = 'abc%';
SET @ClientName = '%abc%';
SET @ClientName = '%abc';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @ClientName VARCHAR(20) = 'abc' 

SELECT ID,ClientName 
FROM    ClientTable 
WHERE   ClientName LIKE '%'+@ClientName+'%'
```